# Why does angular tests fail sometimes?

Tags: angular, jasmine

I'm getting sometimes this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined thrown
```

Often all the tests works, but sometimes some tests just fail. Why is that?

I've tried with on tests:

> afterEach(() => {
>       fixture.destroy();   });

Comment: There is no call stack with the error?

Comment: Most likely a race condition of mocking or providing an observable or the observables.